# Authenticate with cypress using Auth0

Tags: authentication, testing, cypress, auth0, google-authentication

We want to authenticate a user using Auth0 Google integration throughout cypress.

We have created a specific user for cypress to authenticate with user/password connection in Auth0.

The issue is, we don't want to allow user/password on the Auth0 UI, so it looks like we cannot authenticate this way.

I've give this guide a try: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication#Custom-Command-for-Auth0-Authentication but we are getting this error `Grant type 'password' not allowed for the client.`

Is there any other way to enhance the bellow guide and authenticate with Google instead?

Open to suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This error `Grant type 'password' not allowed for the client`, usually means that this grant type is not checked. You can check by logging in in your Auth0 dashboard, go to Applications/ Enter the application used/ Settings/ Scroll to the Advanced settings/ Grant Types.
There you can see multiple types of grant and need to check the `Password` type and save changes.

Hope this helps!